# Error propagation of measurements in linear regression

Tags: regression, error-propagation

I apologise in advance for not using the correct vocabulary.

I have a set of independent measurements $p_i:=(x_i, y_i)$. Each point has a fixed uncertainty  $\Delta_p:=(\Delta_x, \Delta_y)$ i.e. the results can be written as

$(x_1 \pm \Delta_x, y_1 \pm \Delta_y), \ldots, (x_n \pm\Delta_x, y_n \pm \Delta_y)$.

Linear regression for the points $p_i$ results in a function of the form $f(x) = a\cdot x + b$

My question: How can I calcuate the error/uncertainty propagation for the slope $a$. I mean the uncertainties of the points should have some effects on the result. My goal is to get a value $\Delta_a$ i.e. the slope has the form $a \pm \Delta_a$.

My idea was the usage of the Gausian error propagation. For this, I would use the definition of the slope in the linear regression model

\begin{equation}
a = \frac{n \sum\nolimits_{i=1}^{n} x_i \cdot y_i - \sum\nolimits_{i=1}^{n} x_i \cdot \sum\nolimits_{i=1}^{n} y_i}{n \sum\nolimits_{i=1}^{n} x_i^2 - (\sum\nolimits_{i=1}^{n} x_i)^2}
\end{equation}

and then use the definition of the error propagation
\begin{equation}
\Delta_a^2  = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{\partial a}{\partial x_i} \Delta_x\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial a}{\partial y_i} \Delta_y\right)^2
\end{equation}

Is this the correct way?

Comment: Are you after a so-called "measurement error model"? https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/016974399180033M (there are more recent text books).   Sometimes called errors-in-variables models.

Comment: Not really, I guess. My question was, if I use points with an fixed uncertainty in a linear regression, the slope of the resulting function should also have an uncertainty. My question is how to calculate it. Maybe I am wrong but the uncertantiy in the points/measurements should somehow effect the resulting linear function right?

Comment: yeah, I thought that's what measurement error models did????